# Region of Covergence of $x(t) = e^{-2(t-3)} u(t-3)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I was answering a question bank just to see what I have become and how my math skills fare after understanding some topics when a wild question
 appeared. It goes like this:

> Determine the region of convergence of the Laplace transform of $$x(t) = e^{-2(t-3)} u(t-3)$$

**My work**

I got to find first the Laplace transform of $x(t) = e^{-2(t-3)}
   u(t-3)$. But there's a problem: I don't know how to find the Laplace
   transform of  $$x(t) = e^{-2(t-3)} u(t-3)$$ because of the pesky
   expression $t-3$, which I think, is a time delay. I barely had
   experiences with those kinds of  getting Laplace transforms
   before...so I turned here for help.

How to get the Laplace transform of $$x(t) = e^{-2(t-3)} u(t-3)$$,
   and ultimately, getting its region of convergence?

Comment: There is a table of laplace transform properties that we used in my signal processing class. You can prove this time shift property, but regardless, it basically gives you the answer. One such table: http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplacePropTable.html

Answer (score 1):

The unit step function determines from which value of $t$ your function will be different of $0$.

So, if we have:

$$
u(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{$t \geq 0$} \\
0, & \text{$t<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

With the time shift we have:

$$
u(t-3) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{$t \geq 3$} \\
0, & \text{$t<3$}
\end{cases}
$$

Applying the Laplace Transform integral, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
X(s)&=\int_{3}^{\infty}e^{-2(t-3)}e^{-st}dt\\
&=\int_{3}^{\infty}e^{-t(2+s)}e^{6}dt\\
&=e^{6}\int_{3}^{\infty}e^{-t(2+s)}dt\\
&=e^{6}\left[-\frac{e^{-t(2+s)}}{(2+s)}\right]_{3}^{\infty}\\
&=\frac{e^{6}}{s+2}\left[e^{-3(s+2)}-\color{blue}{\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}e^{-t(s+2)}}\right]\\
&=\frac{e^{-3s}}{s+2}
\end{align}$$

Now, we use the part in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ to find the $ROC$ of this Laplace Transform. In essence, we can say that:

$$ROC=\left\{s:\left|\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}e^{-t(s+2)}\right|<\infty\right\}$$

So

$$
\begin{gather}
\left|\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}e^{-t(s+2)}\right|<\infty\\
\left|\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}e^{-2t}e^{-st}\right|<\infty\\
\left|\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}e^{-2t}e^{-t(\sigma+j\omega)}\right|<\infty\\
\left|\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}e^{-t(2+\sigma)}e^{-j\omega t}\right|<\infty\\
\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}\left|e^{-t(2+\sigma)}\right|<\infty\\
\end{gather}
$$

This will only be true if:

$$
\begin{align}
2+\sigma&>0\\
\sigma&>-2
\end{align}
$$

So the region of convergence comprises all values of $s=\sigma+j\omega=\Re\{s\}+j\Im\{s\}$ so that $\Re\{s\}>-2$ and $\Im\{s\}\in \mathbb{R}$

Which is correct for a causal signal.